# Spectrum measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements, spectroscopy, hydrogen

How can the spectrum of hydrogen be measured (Lyman series, Balmer series, Paschen series and so on)? I mean schema of measurement circuit and the measuring technique (including all the steps needed). Is there any difference between the spectrum of atomic and molecular hydrogen?

Comment: (+1) Here I show how to measure the emission spectra of hydrogen atoms and hydrogen molecules: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/768678/313612. My spectrograph only covers the nominal visible range: about 400 nm to about 700 nm. With extended spectral range collimation lens and camera, I could extend into the UV and IR. And there are other spectrometers that can do likewise. Not so hard nowadays. Hope this helps a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

googling "introduction to experimental atomic spectroscopy" gives some pretty nice results.

And yes, the spectrum of atomic and molecular hydrogen is radically different. [This question](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=500800) at physicsforums correctly points the user to the NIST spectra database.

One should keep in mind that not all of the possible emission/absorption lines will show up in any given experiment and a lot depends on the exact conditions the gas is in. A nice introduction to this is in [Condon and Shortley](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Theory_of_Atomic_Spectra.html?id=hPyD-Nc_YmgC&redir_esc=y).